# How to secure web api (without login) using asymmetric encryption technique?

Tags: cryptography, asp.net-core-webapi, rsa, asp.net-core-6.0

I have created a Web API (.net core 6.0) that will be consumed by 3 of my clients. Requirement is that each client will have a unique key for decryption. There is no login here. How should I implement this?

[This one here](https://codingsonata.com/secure-asp-net-core-web-api-using-api-key-authentication/) (not asymmetric) is key based approach, where key is extracted from the request header and matched with the key in appsettings.json. Is this a safe approach?

Comment: you can think of doing certificate based authentication also.

Comment: @CodingMytra I hv used public key/private key (RSA) to encrypt/decrypt short strings. Here I m looking to secure end points.